# In Jupyter, creating label with tag does not work with aligned

Tags: horizontal-alignment, mathjax

In my Jupyter notebook I am left-aligning equations, and label them manually using `\tag{}`. I need to manually label them because in Jupyter, the [equation numbering gets reset between cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61884029/latex-equation-number-between-cells-in-jupyter-resets-to-1). For the following, `aligned` and `tag` seem to not be playing nicely together. The following:

```
$$
\begin{equation} \tag{fun system}
\begin{aligned}
&x = 1 \\
&y = 2 + 2x^2
\label{1}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$
```

Renders as:

[image: wrong label]

Instead of showing the label `(fun system)`. When I remove `\aligned{}` tag, the label I want shows fine, but now the equations are no longer aligned as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be borderline off-topic, as it's about MathJax (which is not TeX), but if you place the `\tag` after the `aligned` you get `(fun system)`.

[image]

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&x = 1 \\
&y = 2 + 2x^2
\end{aligned}
\tag{fun system}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Thanks -- I am enough of a noob with both that I don't know when I have a mathjax problem versus a Tex problem vs a Jupyter problem. Would stack overflow be a better place to ask? I came here because these types of Q's regarding latex rendering in jupyter pretty much get ignored there.

Comment: @eric It's perhaps a bit of a gray area, in this specific case with LaTeX you get the same result regardless of whether `\tag{..}` is placed before or after `aligned`, indicating that it's MathJax' problem. I guess SO is the "proper" place for most such questions, yes.